# when using templates C++ "const" mystery overloaded function call

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question with the code below. When I compile it it complains with this error below. Now my question is if I remove the "const" in the declaration  and change it to only :

```
template<class T> T max( T& left, T& right);
```

it becomes okay and the compiles/executes correctly. How come the compiler thinks that the call is ambiguous? Shouldn't the forward declaration follow the implementation?

```
==== start of error message====
max.cpp:10:34: error: call of overloaded ‘max(int, int)’ is ambiguous
max.cpp:10:34: note: candidates are:
max.cpp:5:21: note: T max(const T&, const T&) [with T = int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:210:5: note: const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int]
max.cpp:11:44: error: call of overloaded ‘max(double, double)’ is ambiguous
max.cpp:11:44: note: candidates are:
max.cpp:5:21: note: T max(const T&, const T&) [with T = double]

=======end of error message===
```

=============code starts here======

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T> T max(const T& left, const T& right);

int main(void)
{

      cout<<"max int:"<<  max(1,4)<<endl;
      cout<<"max double:"<<  max(5.02,1.002)<<endl;

}

template<class T>
T max(const T& left, const T& right)
{

      return left > right? left:right;
}
```

Comment: Another case of the `using namespace std;`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do:

```
  cout<<"max int:"<<  ::max(1,4)<<endl;
  cout<<"max double:"<<  ::max(5.02,1.002)<<endl;
```

Since there is another `max` defined in `std` namespace. You have to inform the compiler to use the `max` defined in global namespace, which is the one you defined. See a live example here: [Function template Demo](http://ideone.com/4KOrRS)

If you look at the `std::max` defined in std namespace:

```
template <class T> const T& max (const T& a, const T& b);
```

which returns const reference and takes const reference to parameters, that's why when you remove const, it will compile. Hope that this helps.

Comment: So what you are saying is that my declaration is colliding with the one in the std namespace right? and this is because my declaration has the same parameters with the one from std but different return type (const T& versus T only). Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The std namespace has a max already built in, so you can either not have the line `using namespace std;` or put the max function in your own namespace.

```
namespace myNamespace {  
    //your max function  
}
```

Comment: or use the scope resolution operators ``::`` before ``max`` in order to look into global scope, as stated in other answers. i.e. ``::max``

Answer (score 0):

We have few functions already defined in std namespace like max(), swap() qsort(). So when you define your own function

```
max(const T& left,const T& right)
```

it is same as one in std namespace hence the error. So you can do following to make it work

1. call your function using scope resolution operator **::max(x,y)**
2. remove const qualifier from your function

Answer (score 0):

As others have written the compiler has found a max function additionally in namespace std. Now it tries to get the best version for you via function overloading. As both signatures are eaqual it can not choose a best version and complains. Now if you remove const the compiler can not bind a integer (or double) literal to a non const refference. Now it has only one choice and takes std::max functionality. You can see it with the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace ns1 {

    template<class T>
    void doit(T const&) {
        std::cout << "ns1::doit" << std::endl;
    }
}

template<class T>
void doit(T&) {
    std::cout << "::doit" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    using namespace ns1;
    int i=1;
    int const j=1;
    doit(1);
    doit(i);
    doit(i+1-1);
    doit(j);
    return 0;
}
```

As everithing is an int the compiler has to choose a non const reference only if it has a non const variable (i). In other cases it choose the cont reference version from namespace ns1. It could even bind temporaries to const references (i+1-1).The same happens with your max and std::max.

*Edit*:

I forgott to say if you remove the const in your declaration the compiler choose std::max which is of course correct but not yours.